# Calibre server doesn't start on Ubuntu server 16.10 with systemd

Tags: server, systemd, calibre

I am trying to get Calibre server to start automatic during startup.
I have used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-calibre-ebook-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial.
Then I've used this script:

```
[Unit]
Description=Calibre Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=calibre
Group=calibre
ExecStart=/usr/bin/calibre-server \
        --daemonize \
        --max-cover=600x800 \
        --max-opds-items=30 \
        --max-opds-ungrouped-items=100 \
        --username=calibre \
        --port=9000 \
        --pidfile=/var/run/calibre-server.pid \
        --with-library=/jan/home/calibre-library/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

to create an auto startup in systemd.
If I manualy startup with: systemctl start calibre.service
It seems to execute.
If I give the command: systemctl status calibre.service, I get the following result:

```
● calibre.service - Calibre Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/calibre.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2017-05-25 21:55:51 CEST; 45s ago
  Process: 1887 ExecStart=/usr/bin/calibre-server --daemonize --max-cover=600x800 --max-opds-items=30 --max-opds-ungrouped-items=100 --username=calibre --port=
 Main PID: 1887 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 25 21:55:50 FileServer systemd[1]: Started Calibre Service.
May 25 21:55:50 FileServer calibre-server[1887]: No write acces to
```

/home/calibre/.config/calibre using a temporary dir instead

But when I look in my browser there is no calibre home page on http://192.168.0.100:9000, this is my home server.
Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Add `Type=forking` to the `[Service]` section and retry lets see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `--pidfile=/var/run/calibre-server.pid` which tell calibre to write the pid file to `/var/run`. Most likely the user running the process `User=calibre` does not have access to write there. I'd suggest you remove `--pidfile` since you're not using it.

If you do want to use it, change the path to a writeable directory by the `calibre` user and add `PIDFile=/dir/with/pidfile/calibre-server.pid` before your `ExecStart` line, and as mentioned above also add `Type=forking`

Answer (score 0):

I am running a Calibre server successfully on 18.04, so hopefully these suggestions apply to your distribution as well.

I would change the Type to "oneshot" and remove the "--daemonize" tag because it doesn't need to be there since you're running it from systemd anyway. If you are running the current version of calibre then you need to remove the "--with-library" tag and just leave the last line as "/path/to/calibre/library".

Additionally, you specify a username but no password. Not sure if that causes problems, but it might be better to create a user database and then pass the option "--enable-auth" to your server command to activate your users (see the [calibre user manual](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/cli-index.html#documented-commands)) along with "--userdb /path/to/users.sqlite". If you need more information on how to do this I can expand.

Lastly, since it hasn't been mentioned yet, please make sure the port you are using is allowed through your firewall and forwarded by your router properly.